# Customizing Jmeter JSON Extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

With the JSON Extractor you can save all elements found to an array, then concatenate all array elements if you select "concatenation var.

However how can you customize how the concatenation is done ?.
Specifically I'd like to wrap each element within double quotes.
Ex "5723","5796","8901"

The default gives you :
5723,5796,8901

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSON Extractor documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

> If many results are found, plugin will concatenate them using `,` separator and store it in a var named `<variable name>_ALL`

So as of JMeter 3.3 it is not possible to add any extra characters during concatenation.

---

If you need to surround the individual results with quotation marks you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead. Groovy has built-in JSON support so you should be able to implement your requirement using code like:

```
def results = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).read('YOUR_JSONPATH_HERE')
def builder = new StringBuilder()
results.eachWithIndex{ entry, idx ->
    builder.append('"').append(entry).append('"')
    if (idx < results.size() -1) {
        builder.append(',')
    }
}

vars.put('YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE', builder.toString())
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)